# Get result of a non generic task

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to get the result of a `Task<T>` when it has been downcast to the non generic `Task`?
I know this is possible to do with Reflection, but is there a way to do it without? Maybe by the use of `Expression`?
Here's an example of what I want to do:

```
RunResult RunTask(Task task)
{
    task.Wait();

    object result = ???;

    if (result is RunResult)
        return (RunResult)result;

    return RunResult.Success;
}
```

I know that I can accomplish this by having a different overload, but I do not like that the behavior changes depending on which overload is picked.

If the task doesn't have a result, then null is fine in this situation.

Comment: It sounds like you'd be better off converting your tasks into a `Task<RunResult>` instead.

Comment: @Asad I agree, that would be a good way to do it, but unfortunately the tasks are already passed through the system as the base type.

Comment: `RunResult` would just be an enum, but it could be much more complex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be a `Task<RunResult>`, right? Then cast it to that type and extract the result.

If this guess of mine was wrong, you can use `dynamic` to quickly get to the value of the `Result` property.

```
((dynamic)myTask).Result
```

Now this resulting value is of type `dynamic` so I'm not sure how you want to extract data from it.

Comment: This would work (Result could be assigned to an object, it would throw if it was a non generic `Task` which could be caught). Unfortunately this involves the DLR, which is a whole other beast.

Comment: Do you know what the actual generic type parameter is or not? Then just cast to that type.

Comment: This would work fine, since you're safely testing for is before running a conversion over the data. Good place
 to use it!

Comment: @usr No I don't and to solve that we have to check the entire class hierarchy (which for RunResult would just be RunResult and object - but potentially many more).

Comment: @Janiels in the other answer you have found out that you need reflection here. You also seem to care about performance. Note, that dynamic is likely faster than reflection. It generates code at runtime (once) specialized to the actual runtime types.

Comment: I ran some tests and it is correct that dynamic is faster than Reflection (by about 30% in my tests). A specialized Expression still blows them out of the water and is about 400% faster than using dynamic (but requires some synchronization which my timing doesn't take into account). Direct access is about 700% faster than the expression method. I can post the code in my original question, if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 3):

If you pass in a `Task<T>` instance where the `Result` is something that derives from `RunResult`, you will get that value as the return value of this function.  Otherwise, you will get `null`.

```
RunResult RunTask(Task task)
{
    task.Wait();
    var type = task.GetType();
    if (!type.IsGenericType)
    {
        return null;
    }
    //Could also use: ((dynamic)task).Result as RunResult
    return type.GetProperty("Result").GetValue(task) as RunResult;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you would think so, but consider the case where we have a `Task<object>` that can return a `RunResult`.

Comment: I was hoping there was another way than Reflection to do this.

Comment: @Janiels There isn't, sorry. You need to use reflection if you've previously thrown away the compile-time type.

Comment: Would it not be possible to use [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710.aspx) and make a tree that extracted the Result? And then cache it based on the type of `Task`? I am pretty sure that is the most performant way to do this, but I just wondered if it was possible to do in a more.. "static" way

Comment: @Janiels That doesn't make sense to do. Why are you so opposed to using reflection when you're in a situation that reflection is designed for?

Comment: I am not opposed as it would not matter in my case, but in a high performance scenario then Reflection would be slow in comparison. I was hoping there was a clean, C#'ish way to do it, but alas, I see that there isn't.

Comment: @Janiels The ultimate "C#-ish" way would probably be to have an object model where you can access a `RunResult` from your tasks directly, regardless of their type. Your current model doesn't support that (and there's probably a good reason why) and thus you're forced to use more unseemly methods.

Comment: @Janiels "I was hoping there was a clean, C#'ish way to do it, but alas, I see that there isn't." The clean way to do it is to not throw away your types. You've presented a question that has restricted the set of possible solutions, all of which **require** reflection.

Comment: @TimothyShields Which is what my question was - whether or not Reflection was required. Even writing expression trees would require Reflection, so this is seemingly the only answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.threading.tasks.task) Does not expose a "Result" property, and since [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not contravariant (ie the `<T>` is not `<out T>`) you can't simply cast to a `Task<object>`.

One way other than reflection would be to have a generic method handle your code. Since Methods can be generics, you can pass this through to the task. This has the added advantage that you can call the method without explicitly setting the generic paraneters, since they can be inferred from usage by the compiler.

```
RunResult RunTask<T>(Task<T> task)
{
    task.Wait();

    T result = task.Result;

    if (result is RunResult)
        return (RunResult)result;

    return RunResult.Success;
}
```

Comment: Only interfaces and delegates can have  contra-/covariant type parameters, so it wouldn't even be possible to make T covariant. But the problem with this approach is the same as Timothy Shields answer; we still have to check `Task<object>` and `Task<RunStatus>`; potentially many other variations.

Comment: I do not really get your question. You want to extract Result from the non generic Task and if it is a RunResult deliver it, but you do not want to check and cast the result to the RunResult. In addition to that you reject using reflection and dynamic typing. So tell us what are your criteria for a correct answer, instead of just rejecting every possibility offered.

Comment: My question is if it is possible to do without Reflection (as my question actually says). The dynamic way is a good way but unfortunately loads the DLR in which case I would rather fall back to Reflection. It is not possible to cast the `Task` to a `Task<RunResult>`, because it could be a `Task<object>` and still return a `RunResult`. If it were a more complex type, there would be many different variations of `Task<T>` to check.

Comment: Why don't you like reflection solution in the first place?

Comment: The Reflection way is fine (albeit Reflection API's are slow, not that it would matter in my case). The problem is that I was hoping there would be a better, more "static" approach.

Comment: Reflection is slow, and without the nameof operator (coming in C# 6.0) it makes the code harder to maintain, and with or without the code is harder to read.

Comment: I would not agree with the statement "reflection is slow". Reflection is not slow, it is just slower then direct calls. The real question is, is that much "slower" acceptable or not for your application?