# Cast object to Task<T> and set T from variable with type Type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, generics, reflection

It's a little bit difficult to explain, I apologies for that. But I need help.
I'm working on generic approach for events. All my code base on [eShopOnContainers example](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusServiceBus/EventBusServiceBus.cs#L184) but my handlers should return a value.

In eShopOnContainers there is just `Task` as a return type, so they can easy

```
var eventType = _subsManager.GetEventTypeByName(eventName);
var integrationEvent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(message, eventType);
var concreteType = typeof(IIntegrationEventHandler<>).MakeGenericType(eventType);
await (Task)concreteType.GetMethod("Handle").Invoke(handler, new object[] { integrationEvent });
```

Let's say I have

```
public interface IRequestMessageHandler<in TRequest, TReply>
    {
        Task<TReply> Handle(TRequest request);
    }
```

In my case, I need to cast to `Task<T>`. Type for `T` store in variable

```
Type concreteHandlerType = typeof(IRequestMessageHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(subscription.RequestType, subscription.ReplyType);
Type concreteReplyType = typeof(Task<>).MakeGenericType(subscription.ReplyType);
```

Then I need cast result to `concreteReplyType`

```
var reply = await (concreteReplyType)concreteType.GetMethod("Handle")?.Invoke(handler, new[] { integrationEvent });
```

Please help me because I don't understand how it is possible. Thank you in advance.
Please let me know what information should I add to help you more understand.

Fiddle with code to reproduce https://dotnetfiddle.net/X3m4A1

Comment: It looks like what you want to do is to cast to an arbitrary generic type at runtime.  Why?  You won't get any compile-time type safety by doing that; you might as well use `object` or `dynamic`.  Microsoft uses `object` for its events; at runtime, you simply cast to the expected object type.

Comment: I need `await`. In example eShop it just `await Task` but I need `await Task<sometype>` and get `response`. Not sure that it's cleer. maybe I'm wrong. What can you advice? How to get response object?

Comment: `await Task<object>` or await `Task<dynamic>`

Comment: Normally you use `dynamic` for that (see this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838513/get-result-of-a-non-generic-task))

Comment: @RobertHarvey No can do. `Task<>` isn't co/contravariant

Comment: I tried `var reply = await (Task<dynamic>)concreteType.GetMethod("Handle")?.Invoke(handler, new[] { integrationEvent });` but got `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[ConsoleApp9.ReplyMessageExample]' to type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Object`

Comment: Single-method, fully generic interfaces like `IRequestMessageHandler` are often just unnecessarily complicated ways of reinventing `Func`. This case looks no different. The amount of code in the linked codebase that actually performs useful work, as opposed to plumbing, seems very low.

Comment: @xanatos: Are you trying to tell me that you can't await an `object` or a `dynamic`?  That seems really unlikely.

Comment: cast to `Task<dynamic>` doesn't work

Comment: @DavidRoss: I suggest you check out the source code for Dapper.  They do this all the time, and half of their functions are `async`.  https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper

Comment: @DavidRoss You can't cast `Task<Foo>` to `Task<object>` or `Task<dynamic>`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I prepare Fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/X3m4A1 Could you please look?

Comment: It would be immensely helpful if you could explain what your use case is.  https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @RobertHarvey yeah, I know it is little bit unclear. But it is difficult to short explain. Sorry. It seems that the answer solves my problem

Comment: thank you all. you helped to solve my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve your problem a simple solution is to use `dynamic` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23838563/613130)).

```
var method = concreteType.GetMethod("Handle");
var task = (Task)method.Invoke(handler, new object[] { integrationEvent });

await task;

object result = ((dynamic)task).Result;
```